# How can I react to a checkbox in a map?

Tags: reactjs

How can I toggle a checkbox in a map when I click on it?
So only set to true or false which one was clicked.
Then I would like to either pack the value of the checkbox, in this case the index, into an array or delete it from it.

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
  const copy = teilen;
  setChecked(event.target.checked);
   if (event.target.checked) 
   {
     setTeilen(teilen, event.target.value);
   } else {
     copy.splice(event.target.value, 1);
     setTeilen(copy);
   }

 console.log(teilen);
};

 [...]

  pdfs.map((p, index) => (

 [...]

 <Checkbox
  value={p._id}
  index={p._id}
  checked={checked}
  onChange={handleChange}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
  />

  [...]

 ))}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to map an array and end result would be  a multi-select checkbox ?

Comment: No - i want that when i click on a checkbox, the value of this checkbox are stored to an array if the checkbox is set to true. Otherwise the value, if it is stored in the array, should remove from that

Comment: setTeilen is an array?

Comment: Please post a more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can try something like this:

```js
const checkboxes = [
  {
    name:"a",
    value:"a",
    checked:false
  },
  {
    name:"b",
    value:"b",
    checked:false
  },
  {
    name:"c",
    value:"c",
    checked:false
  },
];

const checkedArray = [];

const handleChange = (e) => {
              if(e.target.checked){
                checkedArray.push(item.value);
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
              } else {
                if(checkedArray.contains(item.value)){
                  checkedArray.filter(arrItem => arrItem === item.value);
                }
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
              }

const render = () => {
  return checkboxes.map((item,i) => (
    <input type="checkbox" 
    value={item.value} 
    name={item.value} 
    checked={item.checked}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
  ))
}
```

and you must keep the data in state to make component re-render.